# powershell script to compare parameters between two files and override values into main file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm new to power shell and i would greatly appreciate you all if you can help me to fix this.
if child file existed, I need to compare two parameters ($$Daily_Test, $$Monthly_Test) and replace child values into parent file.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to add text to the question as it is asking me format. Instead that, added image. can you please check my question in image

Comment: Please read through [ask] - We'll really need your actual code that you're using in Powershell, to update it effectively.  Please put your code into the question via en [edit] and feel free to remove the photo once you provide that data via text as well.

Comment: Also - please specify what specific version of Powershell you're using, you aren't using three different versions simultaneously, surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if below commands help you. Based on your example content will first process the child file and create a dictionary, and then update the all matching keys **(all, not just specifically $$Daily_Test and $$Monthly_Test)** in parent file if they are present in the child file; key being the part before `=` sign.

I would suggest to create a copy of parent file before testing this. This has been tested on PowerShell 5.1.

```bsh
# Read the contents of both files
$parentContent = @(Get-Content -Path .\parent.txt)
$childContent = @(Get-Content -Path .\child.txt)

# Create a dictionary to hold values from child file
$childDict=@{}
$childContent | ForEach-Object -Process {
$spl = $_ -split '='
if ($spl.Count -eq 2 -and -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($spl[1])) { $childDict.Add($spl[0], $spl[1]) }
}

# Update the values from child in parent content

$modifiedParentContent=@()

$parentContent | ForEach-Object -Process {
$line = $_
$spl = $line -split '='
if ($spl[0] -in $childDict.Keys) {
$modifiedParentContent += "$($spl[0])=$($childDict[$spl[0]])"
}
else {
$modifiedParentContent += $line
}
}

# Overwrite the parent file
Set-Content -Path .\parent.txt -Value $modifiedParentContent
```